# Renaming files in a folder with ascending numbers but one random number is missing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, rename, file-rename

```
import os

def main():
    for count, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(r'C:\users\praba\videos')):
        src =os.path.join(r'C:\\users\\praba\\videos\\'+filename)
        des =os.path.join(r'C:\\users\\praba\\videos\\'+str(count+1)+".png")
        os.rename(src,des)
    print "Task Completed!!!"
main()
```

I tried to rename files with the number from 1 to N. But the output always misses one number in the renamed files.

In this below image, the number 13 is missing. What could be wrong with my code?

[image: rename]

Comment: just add a print and see whats happening ... at a guess you had a 13.png already in the folder so it renamed to 13.png, and then moved it to 14.png or something

Comment: what are the names of the files before you run the script?

Comment: @JoranBeasley I tried to print the names. There was a file named 13.png. But It didn't display. When I tried to rename the 14th file into 13.png, it said that the 13.png file already exists. I ran an automated script to paste all images one by one on the google slides website. I found that the 13th image slide was a complete white aka empty.

Comment: @buran Those files were from VLC player's snapshot tool. So the filename was like this vlcsnap-2020-06-14-17h08m39s422.png

Comment: what if I would like to pass directory and new names as arguments of function "main"?